# Add two list data into array while using if condition

Tags: c#, .net

I have two lists, one list have some record (not known specific no of rec, but not more than 13 records) and second list have only empty value. I am using if condition on these two list. And want to add these two list in one array. I am using this code:

```
for (int i=0; i>12; i++)
{
    List<string> excList = new List<string>();
    //added column from table, which can varies
    excList.Add((string)column.ColumnName);
    string[] excelList = new string[] {  };
    List<string> stack = Enumerable.Range(excList.Count, 13)
                .Select(z => string.Empty)
                .ToList<string>();
    if (excList.Count > i)
    {
        excelList =  excList.ToArray();
    }
    if (excList.Count <= i)
    {
         excelList = stack.ToArray();
    }
    eCol0 = excelList[0].ToString();
    //show first value, after adding two list in excelList
    response.Write(eCol0);
}
```

Using this code, when the second condition started and list (excList) is adding in array (excelList) then excelList is showing only second list data.

I want to insert these two list (excList and stack) into arrayList (which have range of 13).But these two list must add on the bases of if condition as I'm using if condition in above code.

Comment: Did you say one of the lists was empty?

Comment: You instantiate your excel lisdt within the loop. So each iteration a new variable is created and instantiated. Create and instatiate the excellist before the for loop.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Please [edit] to clarify. (1) there is no second loop. (2) Your expected result is unclear.

Comment: @CaiusJard yes.

Comment: If you want two lists as one, and you seem to be OK with using LINQ, why don't you just do `a.Concat(b)`?

Comment: What is the point of adding an empty list to an array? If you have `emptyList` and `fullList` the resulting array will be the same as calling `fullList.ToArray()`

Comment: sorrry to all. I am tell about if condition and for loop. Check my updated question. Thanks.

Comment: @CaiusJard i am using emptyList because i want to add list deponding on if condition. i means if listOfValue(named as excList) have 4 record then its will add in array and more than 4 records to 13. Put empty/null value. Hope, u understand

Comment: Might also be worth pointing out a for loop like `for(int i = 0;  i > 12 ...)` will never run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you never Add something to your string array excelList. You always assign it new.

Using an array is also not the best for adding values, since you need to know beforehand the size of the array.

If you really want an array in the end with both results, you should do something like this:

```
        List<string> excList = new List<string>();

        ... fill your excList here and initialize the stack list with whatever you need ...

        excList.AddRange(stack);

        string[] excelList = excList.ToArray();
```

Edit: as the comments mention, your question is a little bit confusing and you are using one big loop with no clear reason why and adding empty values makes no sence too... so i tried to get the essence out of what you wanted to know

Edit:2
Wait a second, I think you want in the end, an array of strings, with the size of 13, where the elements are at least string.empty

```
            List<string> excList = new List<string>();
            //added column from table, which can varies
            excList.Add((string)column.ColumnName);

            string[] excelList = new string[13];

            for (int i = 0; i < excList.Count; i++)
            {
                excelList[i] = excList[i];
            }

            for (int i = excList.Count; i < 13; i++)
            {
                excelList[i] = string.Empty;
            }
```

no outer loop necessary

Comment: Actually, i want to hold 13 records in one array(named as excelList). But using one list if list have only 4 records then more then for more than 4 records, its give out of index error. So give any update in above your answer. If u r not cleared again, then ask freely. Thanks for reply, but its not working.

Comment: @scoop when exactly do you get the out of index error? Here: `eCol0 = excelList[0].ToString();`?

So do you want in the end, always an array with a fix size of 13? 

Edit: saw you second answer to slow

Comment: And one Change on first for loop: excelList[i] = excList[i]; .

Answer (score 0):

You've written a huge amount of confusing code that could be considerably more compact.

Through th commnts I was able to understand that you have a list of N strings, where N could be between 1 and 13, and you want to turn it into an array of 13 strings with all your list items at the start, and empty strings at the end

So a list of:

```
"a", "b", "c"
```

Becomes an array of:

```
"a", "b", "c", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
```

---

If you want a one liner to generate you a list of 13 strings, from a List `x` of up to 13 strings:

```
string[] arrayOf13 = x.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat("", 13 - x.Count)).ToArray();
```

If your list `x` will have an unknown number more than 13:

```
string[] arrayOf13 = x.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat("", 13)).Take(13).ToArray();
```

Or without LINQ using either a for or a while loop:

```
for(; x.Count < 13; x.Add(""))
string[] arrayOf13 = x.ToArray();

while(x.Count < 13) 
  x.Add(""));
string[] arrayOf13 = x.ToArray();
```

If you're willing to have the strings be null rather than empty, you can just declare an array of size 13 (all null) and then use `Array.CopyTo()`:

```
string[] arrayOf13 = new string[13];
x.ToArray().CopyTo(arrayOf13, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your goal is to get an array of 13 strings (`excelList`), where each element is eigher `string.Empty` by default or the corresponding (same index) element from some source list (`excList`).

So a short-code solution would be to first create a 13-element array, initialized with 'string.Empty' and then copy the source lists elements over, limited to max 13 elements:

```
var excelList = Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 13).ToArray();

excList.CopyTo(0, excelList, 0, Math.Min(13, excList.Count));
```